# What is a good way to make several attempts to handle one exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Let's say, I have a preferred solution to handle exception.
But exception still occurs sometimes and I have to use the second, less preferred, solution.
I use code like the following, it might look not cool. If there is better practice, please advice.

```
try:
    print(undefined_varible)
except NameError:
    try:
        print("1st attempt to handle NameError exception")
    except NameError:
        print("2nd attempt to handle NameError exception")
```

UPDATE:
here is a piece of my real code

```
import re
def find_phone(text):
    try:
        pattern = re.compile(r"(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?")
        #search for a phone number
        mo = pattern.search(text)
        phone = mo.group()
        print (phone)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            #don't want to use this pattern always because it's too wide and not perfect
            pattern = re.compile(r"(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{1,3})[-. )]*(\d{1,3})[-. ]*(\d{1,4})([-. ]*(\d{1,4}))?([-. ]*(\d{1,4}))?(?: *x(\d{1,4}))?")
            mo = pattern.search(text)
            phone = mo.group()
            print (phone)
        except AttributeError:
            print("phone number has not been found")
find_phone("here is the weird formatted phone number: +33 6 29 37 24 57")
```

Comment: I think the question is too vague to be answered appropriately. If you give an example of the real use case, we might be able to help you more. What's the first call that can fail? A network issue? a check that an element is in a list/dict?

Comment: OK, I've added a piece of code. Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
import re

def find_phone(text):
    pattern_preference = [
        r"(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?", 
        r"(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{1,3})[-. )]*(\d{1,3})[-. ]*(\d{1,4})([-. ]*(\d{1,4}))?([-. ]*(\d{1,4}))?(?: *x(\d{1,4}))?"
    ]
    for pattern in pattern_preference:
        try:
            pattern = re.compile(pattern)
            #search for a phone number
            mo = pattern.search(text)
            phone = mo.group()
            print(phone)
            break
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    else:
        print("phone number has not been found")

find_phone("here is the weird formatted phone number: +33 6 29 37 24 57")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean I have different solutions for one kind of exception. I've updated my question, added real code.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? It allows you do add multiple patterns to patterns_preference.

Comment: It totally does :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have several ways to check for a phone number. One idea is to have a counter in your function and through an `if` statement choose which one to try

```
import re
def find_phone(text):
    number_of_cases = 2
    i = 0
    while i < number_of_cases
        try:
            if i == 0:
                pattern = re.compile(r"(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?")
                #search for a phone number
                mo = pattern.search(text)
                phone = mo.group()
                print (phone)
            elif i == 1:
                #don't want to use this pattern always because it's too wide and not perfect
                pattern = re.compile(r"(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{1,3})[-. )]*(\d{1,3})[-. ]*(\d{1,4})([-. ]*(\d{1,4}))?([-. ]*(\d{1,4}))?(?: *x(\d{1,4}))?")
               mo = pattern.search(text)
               phone = mo.group()
               print (phone)
        except AttributeError:
            i += 1
        else: break
```

Another thought would be to check if you have found a phone number

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to call a function like `group`/`groups` on a None object. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), which states that if there is no matching, None is returned.

So your problem reduces to verify that the result is None.

```
def find_phone(text): 
  pattern = re.pattern(first_pattern)
  match = pattern.search(test)
  if not match:
    pattern2 = re.pattern(second_pattern)
    match2 = pattern2.search(test)
    if not match2:
      return None
  phone = match.group(...)
  return phone
```

However, for readability, I would refactor the code in the first if statement into another function, e.g.,

```
def find_phone_with_special_pattern(text):
  pattern = re.pattern(second_pattern)
  match = pattern.search(test)
  if not match:
    return None
  phone = match.group(...)
  return phone

def find_phone(text): 
  pattern = re.pattern(first_pattern)
  match = pattern.search(test)
  if not match:
    return find_phone_with_special_pattern(text)
  phone = match.group(...)
  return phone
```

And as you can see, this code can be refactored as well:

```
def find_phone_with_pattern(pattern, text):
  pattern = re.pattern(...)
  match = pattern.search(...)
  if not match:
    return None
  phone = match.group(...)
  return phone

def find_phone(text):
  phone = find_phone_with_pattern("normal-pattern-here", text)
  if not phone:
      phone = find_phone_with_pattern("alternative-pattern-here", text)
  return phone
```

This is basically a "retry" mechanism. Sometimes you are lucky and you can implement it this way pretty easily, other times you have to catch Exceptions and think about how to do it.

Comment: re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) returns None if no position in the string matches the pattern. Thanks for pointing at docs and cool solution!

Comment: You are welcome! If you consider this to be the right answer to your question, you can also mark it as the best answer. (you have time to wait for other answers, there are potentially no limits)